# how to save multiple data in shared preferences in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

my app contains a list of dates in which there is toggle button

```
    1.>on check it sets alarm and on uncheck it deletes the alarm
```

these is working normally but when i close aplication then alarm will automaically gets deleted 
so i want to save data in shared preferences when toggle button is clicked and delete particular data when btn is unchek from shared preferneces for this  i am doing

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.dd.mydata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("alarm"+cday+"_"+month,cday);
editor.commit();
```

where cday and month is alarm date and month

on recieve i have to fetch these data and match with date so that alarm can ring
so on recive i am doing this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = arg0.getSharedPreferences("com.example.dd.mydata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = sharedPref.getString("alarm"+cday+"_"+cmonth, null);
```

in these way i am achiving the value of shared preferences in both class but it is working for single toggle button clicking more than 2 button **overrites the also tell me how can i check whether the current dates exists or not in shared prefernces

Comment: I guess you have to set different keys , every time the user click to set an alarm

Comment: either use different keys or use database to keep record

Comment: my cday contains value in the list(which is date of alarm) so for every row it is differnt and i am doing this for setting key editor.putString("alarm"+cday+"_"+month,cday); is this wrong for setting new key every time then what will be correct preocedure for this tell me

Comment: Just append the #index at the end of your key, now just run the forloop and retrive your keys.

Comment: this is working perfectly my shared preferences contains data but how to match it with current date

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`SharedPreferences.contains(String key)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains%28java.lang.String%29) method.

For example, `contains("alarm"+cday+"_"+cmonth)`